# Converting an Activity to a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am converting my Activity to a Fragment.
I need help manipulating my Activity code to run as a Fragment.

I know I have to convert the `onCreate()` method to be `onCreateView()`.
I don't know how to do so.

My code for the onCreate()...

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_author_fact);
        //to eget reference to TextView for the fact
        mAuthorFactTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.authorFactTextView);
    //Extract the resource id for the fact from the intent
    //If none is provided, display the "fact missing" message
    int authorFact = getIntent().getIntExtra(QuoteFragment.EXTRA_AUTHOR_FACT,
            R.string.fact_error);
    // put the fact string in the fact TextView
    mAuthorFactTextView.setText(authorFact);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I need to use this code structure

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bug_list, container, false);

        //Setup floating action button to add a new bug
        final View addButton = v.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
            addBug();
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

How do I do this correctly?
I have tried different things, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: what you didnt understood in it?

Comment: All I understand is that I need to convert the onCreate to onCreateView but the problem is every time I look at the onCreate then at the example onCreateView I get confused on how to even start converting it.

Comment: replace setContentView by  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bug_list, container, false);

Comment: Keep the FloatingActionButton stuff in the Activity.  Keep the code that gets the authorFact from the Intent in the Activity.  Pass the authorFact into the Fragment (through the constructor would work).  The only thing you need in onCreateView() in the new Fragment is setting the text in the TextView.

Comment: Ok so what I did for what I understand is, I changed the onCreate line from protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) to public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState). I also changed setContentView(R.layout.activity_author_fact); to View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment, container, false); and I added return v to the very end but the @override is underline red. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you extending Fragment or are you still extending Activity?

Comment: SingleFragmentActivity like i am asked to do, but that too is underlined

Comment: A FragmentActivity is not a Fragment, it's an Activity.....    Is this what you're using?  https://github.com/tkunstek/android-big-nerd-ranch/blob/master/20_CameraImage_CriminalIntent/src/com/bignerdranch/android/criminalintent/SingleFragmentActivity.java

Comment: When it was an activity yes but then I changed it to singlefragmentactivity and in that i have protected abstract Fragment createFragment(); whichs chenges it to a fragment I believe

Comment: I clicked on that link you have, that is what I am extending my fragment with.

Comment: Thank you for reducing your questions. Now, please make this one an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That would include making the code in your question minimal and runnable so people can perhaps copy your code and change it more easily. This would require you to add your XML layouts and more of the code around the onCreate and onCreateView methods.

Comment: my other question as my whole code I need to change from activity to fragment

Comment: Your other question was closed, so answers can no longer be added.

Answer (score 1):

To briefly address the problem of

> I need to change from activity to fragment

---

Let this be the layout we want to convert. Just a simple RelativeLayout with a centered TextView. You can use the *exact same layout* when you convert the Activity to a Fragment. I named it `fragment_layout.xml`.

Of course, you will later need to change the Activity's layout to include the Fragment, but that was not the question...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:text="Hello World"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is an Activity that we are going to convert. Notice the `setContentView` loads the `fragment_layout.xml` file and it grab out that `TextView` using `findViewById`.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

}
```

And here is the Fragment that will act the exact same as the Activity above. Notice, now using `inflate.inflate` with the `fragment_layout.xml` file to get the View in order to grab out that `TextView` using `rootView.findViewById`.

And `OnCreateView` needs to return that `View` from the `inflater`.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

        textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```