# Converting Activity to Fragment / Unreachable Statement

Tags: android

I tried to convert Activity into a Fragment.

Cant seem to correctly pass the context ( marked the corresponding lines).
Android Studio show that marked lines seem to be unreachable .

1. mRecyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view); // <<<<<
2. mExampleAdapter = new SearchItemAdapter(SearchFragment.this, mExampleList); //<<<<    ( this is from inside a method)

Any help is appriciated !

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);


    mRecyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view); // <<<<<
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


This is another part inside a method with same problem :

mExampleAdapter = new SearchItemAdapter(SearchFragment.this, mExampleList); //<<<<
```

Comment: The `return` statement should be the last line in that method. Once you `return`, execution leaves the method, which is what your error message means. Also, you cannot use `getView()` in `onCreateView()`, as it's what creates the `View` for `getView()`. If you want to find your `View`s in `onCreateView()`, follow the simple example in [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35787883).

Comment: Thx that helped . Though I still cant get the context for the adapter to work.

Comment: A `Fragment` is not a `Context`, so you can't use `SearchFragment.this` for one. Use `getActivity()` instead.